# Cassandra C# driver UDT Mapping - Int to Enum

Tags: c#, enums, cassandra, datastax, user-defined-types

I've got the enum type:

```
public enum SomeType
{
    Type1,
    Type2,
    Type3
}
```

and I'd like to map automatically Cassandra int type to the c# enum. I've tried to define it like:

```
session.UserDefinedTypes.Define(
            UdtMap.For<DefinedType>()
            .Map(a => a.Type, "type"));
// where type of a.Type is SomeType
```

however it throws the "InvalidTypeException" with message " type type Int32 is not assignable to SomeType"

Is it possible to map it automatically ? I've seen some examples of table column mapping  to enumerable, but never any of UDT

Comment: Make sure to assign also integer values to your enum values. Otherwise you might get unexpected results in the future (or when someone adds a value).

Comment: Yeah, I know and I've assigned it. It is quick example. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: It's not supported yet :( https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-381

Comment: any news? solution founded?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra not yet supported enum type in udt,

Alternatively, you can solve the problem as follows

```
public enum SomeType
{
Type1=0,
Type2=1,
Type3=2
}

public SomeType SomeTypeProperty;

public int SomeTypePropertyMapForCassandra
{
 get
 {
 return SomeTypePropertyMapForCassandra;
 }
 set
 {
 this.SomeTypeProperty= (SomeType)value;
 }
}
```